# How can i get meta data about word file in command line using apache tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

HI i am looking to extract meta data about word files like number of pages using apache tika on command line, How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys i figured it out,

I had to download the tika-app-1.5.jar and execute the following command which returned me all the details i wanted

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.docx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.doc
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.pptx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.ppt
```